# Custom labels for limit and break values when using scale_color_binned in r ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to display a discrete scale with custom labels for break points and include limits with custom labels. I am aware of code that works when showing breaks within limits, but when limits are active, labeling no longer works with this method

Here is the method that works:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy, color = year)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_binned(limits = c(1999, 2008),
                    breaks = c(2000, 2002, 2004, 2006),
                    labels = c('2', '3', '4', '5'),
                    show.limits = F) # proof that this method works for breaks WITHIN limits
```

When limits are activated for this plot, ggplot gives an error message and does not render the plot

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy, color = year)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_binned(limits = c(1999, 2008),
                    breaks = c(2000, 2002, 2004, 2006),
                    labels = c('2', '3', '4', '5'),
                    show.limits = T) # method fails when limits are activated
```

> Error in `f()`:
> ! Breaks and labels are different lengths

Breaks and labels are obviously the same length. Perhaps something about activating limits changes how the label vector is formed? I know where to find code for the ggplot2 break vector (using *ggplot_build()* or clicking directly on a saved plot object). I looked through those and found nothing that helped me understand how to resolve this issue.

I also tried these methods and it returned the same error *'breaks and labels are different lengths'*:

```
# this did not work

ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy, color = year)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_binned(limits = c(1999, 2008),
                    breaks = c(2000, 2002, 2004, 2006),
                    labels = c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6')
                    show.limits = T) # added more entries to label vector did not work

# this also did not work

ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy, color = year)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = c(0, 20, 40),
    labels = c("0", "20", "40"))  + 
  scale_color_binned(breaks = c(1999, 2000, 2002, 2004, 2006, 2008),
                     labels = c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'),
                     show.limits = F) # add limits directly to breaks did not work
```

One method that could be used to label each entry is written below. However, this method is tedious if there are several entries for the discrete scale.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy, color = year)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_binned(limits = c('1' = 1999, '6' = 2008),
                    breaks = c('2' = 2000, '3' = 2002, '4' = 2004, '5' = 2006),
                    show.limits = T) # this works, but is a tedious solution when writing several breaks
```

I want to use the scale_color_binned method (or similar functions) because I want to convert continuous scale data to 15-20 discrete ranges and then custom label or suppress labels for different ranges.

Is there a way to generate a ggplot that can accept custom labels for binned continuous values while also showing specified limits for the data?

Comment: UPDATE: This issue has been addressed. See: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4548

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an idea of what's going on if you use a function to label the breaks:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy, color = year)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_binned(limits = c(1999, 2008),
                    breaks = c(2000, 2002, 2004, 2006),
                    labels = ~ print(.x),
                    show.limits = TRUE)
#> [1] 2000 2002 2004 2006
#> [1] 1999 2008
```

You can see that the labels for breaks and for limits are sent in two separate batches to the labelling function, so a fixed-length vector of labels is always going to fail for one or other of these batches. Really, you need a function that can handle either:

```r
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy, color = year)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_binned(limits = c(1999, 2008),
                    breaks = c(2000, 2002, 2004, 2006),
                    labels = ~ if(length(.x) == 2) .x else 1:4,
                    show.limits = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: I wrapped my head for hours in this and noticed that `show.limits` refers to each bin limit: like this code works.  `library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy, color = year)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_binned(limits = c(1999, 2008),
                     breaks = c(2000, 2002),
                     labels = c('2', '3'),
                     show.limits = T)` . But only then when there are two limits. And I was hoping the you or @stefan or @teunbrand will come around and fix it!

Comment: Thank you. This method will suffice for now and is probably among the most efficient solutions given current programming for ggplot2. I can also confirm that replacing the call to print '.x' and '1:4' with character vectors will work using this method. It may be worth submitting a ticket to the ggplot2 github page to request that the behavior of breaks and labels be more intuitive when adding limits.