# How to adjust the label position for a legend with ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, contour

I am plotting a filled contour plot using `ggplot2`, and I'd like to adjust the legend label position. I am not sure if this is doable in `ggplot2`?

The label position in Figure 3 has moved up compared with Figure 2. The label in Figure 3 aligns with the border of the key, and the label in Figure 2 aligns with the center of the key. Also, the label in Figure 3 has "0.040" but Figure 2 does not.

Thanks to the amazing answers, the label position has been solved. One more question that needs to be addressed is: "Can we add "0.040" to the bottom of the legend"? Thank you.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density)) + 
  geom_contour_filled() + 
  scale_fill_brewer(name="Level")

ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density)) + 
  geom_contour_filled() + 
  scale_fill_brewer(name="Level", labels = seq(0,0.04,0.005))
```

**This is the original plot:**

[image]

**This is what I have achieved:**

[image]

**This is what I want to achieve:**

[image]

Comment: I dont see the change in the label position in the latest plot. I just notice that the number of decimals is equal for every value.

Comment: Hi, the label position in Figure 3 has moved up compared with Figure 2. The label in Figure 3 aligns with the border of the key, and the label in Figure 2 aligns with the center of the key. Also, the label in Figure 3 has "0.040" but Figure 2 does not.

Comment: I'm confused. The question says that Figure 3 what you want to achieve. So you don't want the labels aligned with the centers, as in Figure 2? And how did you achieve Figure 3 - do you have code to generate it?

Comment: @neilfws You are correct.  I don't want the labels aligned with the centers, as in Figure 2. I modified Figure 2 using Photoshop to get Figure 3. Thanks.

Comment: Another issue is that you have 8 bins, but you want 9 values, and apparently you want the upper value of the bins except for the first 2 cases? So you need to think about the logic there.

Comment: Oh, I understand. I edited my answer so that it does what you want. However, I don't recommend it. It is harder to read. Most brains are more used to the center aligned text.

Comment: @neilfws I am trying to show the range of the key. For example, the first key actually represents "0.000 - 0.005". Using a centered label, the first key could be identified as "0" and the second key could be identified as "0.005", which is incorrect.

Comment: When ggplot bins continuous data, you can use `show.limits = T` in the `guide` specification. But since `z` is discrete, I'm not sure if there's a way to apply it here. See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71976832/custom-labels-for-limit-and-break-values-when-using-scale-color-binned-in-r-ggpl

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that the legend position varies in your 'This is what i have achieved' plot, versus the original one. The only difference I note is in the number of decimals on of the values of the legend.

Anyway, above I modified your code in case it is useful:

```
ggplot(data_df, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density)) +
  geom_contour_filled() +
  scale_fill_brewer(name = "Level", labels = sprintf("%.3f", seq(0, 0.04, 0.005))) + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.justification = "center", 
        legend.direction = "horizontal")
```

The sprintf command allows you to fix the number of decimals. The legend options in the themen function lets you change the position of the label if that is what you wanted. You can see the options you have in the Help section of the theme function (?theme).

To move just the legend text, you should write

```
ggplot(data_df, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density)) +
  geom_contour_filled() +
  scale_fill_brewer(name = "Level", labels = sprintf("%.3f", seq(0, 0.04, 0.005))) + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(vjust = 1))
```

And change the text position as needed.

Plus, I asked ChatGPT to create a dataset that is useful to replicate your plot in case anybody else wants to contribute (you should always do this, so that others find it easier to help you). Above is the code it generated:

```
# Function to generate density values for a given 'waiting' and 'eruptions' value
generate_density <- function(waiting, eruptions) {
  # Replace this with your desired density function
  # For illustration, we are using a simple example
  density_value <- dnorm(waiting, mean = 50, sd = 10) * dnorm(eruptions, mean = 3, sd = 1)
  return(density_value)
}

# Number of points along 'waiting' and 'eruptions' axes
n_points <- 100

# Generate 'waiting' and 'eruptions' values
waiting_vals <- seq(40, 100, length.out = n_points)
eruptions_vals <- seq(1, 5, length.out = n_points)

# Create an empty dataframe to store the data
data_df <- data.frame(waiting = numeric(0), eruptions = numeric(0), density = numeric(0))

# Populate the dataframe with values and their corresponding densities
for (waiting in waiting_vals) {
  for (eruptions in eruptions_vals) {
    density <- generate_density(waiting, eruptions)
    data_df <- rbind(data_df, data.frame(waiting = waiting, eruptions = eruptions, density = density))
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! `element_text(vjust = 1)` does the trick! Is it possible to add "0.040" to the label (below 0.035)? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for contributing @Santiago, but your answer is incomplete. Adding `theme(legend.text = element_text(vjust = 1))` is good, although I suspect `vjust = 1.25` would be better, but the question is asking how to add "0.040" to the bottom of the legend. Please edit your answer to show OP how to achieve this. Also, the "faithfuld" dataset is an inbuilt 'example' dataset bundled with the ggplot2 package. Using "faithfuld" is more appropriate than your chatGPT example, as it is guaranteed to 'work' for other users.

Comment: I am trying to show the range of each key. For example, the first key represents "0.000 - 0.005" and the last key represents "0.0035 - 0.0040". Using a center label could be misleading in some cases. Thanks.